# API routes that perform actions

Tags: rest, restful-architecture, api-design

So traditional API resources allow you to `GET`, `PUT`, `PATCH`, `DELETE` etc a resource.

```
/api/v1/user/$id
```

However what is the technical term for a route that performs an action and returns some response about the outcome of that action?

```
/api/v1/flushcache
```

Comment: Flushing the cache is not equivalent to `DELETE /api/v1/cache`?

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin I assumed you would need to be able to do other http methods for it to be a resource. From your comment I assume you don't need to do all the methods to be a proper resource then?

Comment: Semantically `DELETE /api/v1/cache` would mean that you actually *delete* the cache, as in, it is no longer there, switched off or removed completely. Flushing is a different case.

Comment: @myol The resource is the thing that lives at an endpoint. All (implemented) methods act on the resource, but not all methods will return a representation of the resource. If the endpoint exists, in REST that means there's a resource there. It is not required to support all methods for that resource.

Comment: *However what is the technical term for a route that performs an action and returns some response about the outcome of that action?* I would say the tech term for that is **RPC**: **R**emote **P**rocedure **C**all

Comment: @EricStein if not all methods are supported is that known as a partial resource?

Comment: You can understand resource as *any information that can be named*, such as *a document or image, a temporal service (e.g. "today's weather in Los Angeles"), a collection of other resources, a non-virtual object (e.g. a person), and so on*. For more details, have a the definition of [*resource*](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1) in Fielding's dissertation.

Comment: @myol I would say there's no such thing as a "partial resource". There may be a "partial representation", which is a representation that doesn't have all the information in the resource. I don't think it's common parlance for "partial" to apply to the set of verbs supported by a resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to just have a `cache` resource:

```
/api/v1/cache
```

Which would return some cache state for example `application/vnd.company.cachestate+json`:

```
{
    "state": "active",
    "objectCount": 123
}
```

Then you could `PUT` the same representation:

```
{
    "state": "flushed"
}
```

Which could return:

```
{
    "state": "active",
    "objectCount": 0
}
```

The point is, you have to first formulate the problem in the existing terminology. The terms used are *always*:

- Resource (what you call 'Route'): An entity that has some business semantics
- Representation: The actual message format used by a Resource. A Resource might support multiple representations!
- Mime-Type: The formal description of a Representation (or multiple ones)

So, again, there is usually no Resource that "does" something, more like, Resources represent some Business Entity, and the standard operations (GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, etc.) are *mapped* to some operations on that entity.

Comment: That's not answering the question. He doesn't want to know the RESTful way to do it, he wants to know the *name* of the non-RESTful way.

Comment: what if the state can not reflect the input easily. Eg. Add a red pen to the jar while removing blue pen. I could represent the jar of pens as a resource and I already am in another endpoint but I want them to be able to change the pens in the jar without passing the entire list of pens (that could be a list of 10s of thousands of pens).